# Get the 3rd largest time value in SQL Server 2018

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the 1st, 2nd, 3rd,...largest value of Time in SQL Server 2018's table.

In my code when I get the 3rd largest, if my month condition is 5, it returns correct value. But if my month condition is 4, it returns the max time value not my expected time value ( 3rd ). I don't know why.

My query:

```
SELECT MAX([Time1].[Time]) FROM [dbo].[index4_MonthChart] as [Time1] 
WHERE 
Month([Time])  = '4'
AND [Time1].[Time] < ( SELECT MAX([Time2].[Time]) FROM [dbo].[index4_MonthChart]  as [Time2] 
WHERE 
[Time2].[Time] < ( SELECT MAX([Time3].[Time]) FROM [dbo].[index4_MonthChart] as [Time3]))
```

All my value in table:

[image]

When month(time) condition is 5, it returns:

[image]

But when month(time) is 4, it always returns the max time value and it is wrong ( The correct time value have to be 2023-04-28 ) :

[image]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Please include the exact output you want here.  And also please one query per question.

Comment: Sorry guys! I'm new so I don't know how to describe exactly my question with image and query.

Comment: I suppose the table shown is time1. You reference time2 in your query. Please give the contents of birth tables as text. A fiddle would be perfect.

Comment: I don't know how to display table data as text I'm sr. It truly returns Time1 ( the 3rd largest time value ). When my Time condition in "Where" is 5, it returns correct value ( 2022-05-21 ) but it is wrong with month(Time) = '4'

Comment: Your "3rd,...largest value" logic in the query doesn't depends on month. You can use row_number() partitioned properly instead.

Comment: Let me google that for you https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2018** version - we have 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017, 2019 and 2022 - so which one are you using in fact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple. You need to add a where clause in your sub-selects to restrict those to Month= 4 as well. Since there are at least two times greater than 30.04 (IE all the times from May), your current query returns the maximum time for April. This doesn't happen for May, because your data has no values later than May.